# Mixing Wheat and IPA for WOW

Tags: beer

So did a tour of Odells with a buddy and his son. During the tour his son asked, "Do you ever mix all the beers into one?" The guide said, "Like a suicide beer? Yes, we've been know to experiment. The best is an IPA and Easy Street Wheat; we call it an Easy Elephant." At the taphouse he gave us a sample.. and it was incredible! Had a sweet and malty start and a grapefruit-like and crisp finish. Now I'm on a quest to make it myself. I could make two batches and then mix them... OR I could experiment. If you were to try to make an Easy Elephant, what would you include?

Comment: I am highly curious about this now, but want to recreate it before going for a batch. Was it basically a 1:1 ratio of wheat to IPA?

Comment: yep - though my measurements were not precise. Fill a pint 50% with IPA, then 50% of the wheat.

Comment: converting to wiki...   there's no real answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a standard Hefe grain bill (half wheat, half 2-row), add in .5lb of medium crystal, and hop it exactly like an IPA. The yeast is up to you. Do you want some hefe yeast flavor in it? Perhaps use the American Wheat yeasts like WLP320, or wb-06 dry. Or just use a standard neutral ale yeast like 1056/001/us-05. Or someing with a little character like wlp028 Kolsch, or wlp029 Scottish. Hmmm the 029 Scottish is jumping out at me for some reason. It should accent that wheaty maltiness nicely and still provide punch to the hops.

For the hops, use whatever kind you like. I prefer EKG, Challenger, Palisades, etc, but if you like American hops, then use them.

Comment: +Check & +1. Hey thanks for the info. I'm always followed a recipe and have created a custom one. Will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a great wheat and hop it like an IPA.  Actually, seeing how the IPA in your example was diluted 2-fold, maybe you hop it like an aggressive american pale ale.
Seeing how [easy street wheat](http://odellbrewing.com/beers/classic/easy_street) is an American wheat beer you can ferment the whole batch with one yeast.  However pitching more than one yeast (yeast blend) works well too.